# What kind of user permissions are needed in order to scan a Salesforce URL with OWASP ZAP?

Tags: salesforce, owasp

We are required to scan a URL that points to a Salesforce Org.  Thus, we need to provide access to the Org to be scanned by OWASP ZAP.  So the question is: what level of user access is needed?  Does it has to be a full Administrator?

We still do not try it yet.  We first need to create a user with the appropriate user access.